# Casperjs: Can't use casper.evaluate() in own function

Tags: casperjs, evaluate

Wtih casperjs I fill a textarea and trigger an event with:

```
casper.thenClick( "#project-bar-yes-no-modal.in button.modal-no", function() { 
    casper.evaluate(function(){
        $("#project-button-textarea-for-testing").val( "// This is a test program\nellipse(100, 100, 100, 102);\n\nrect(50, 50, 50, 50);" ).trigger("set-live-editor");
    });
    this.wait(200);
} );
```

which works fine. When I try to do the same using a function then casper.evaluate() is not called.

```
casper.setLiveEditorCode = function( code ) {
    utils.dump("1");
    casper.evaluate(function(){
        utils.dump("2");
        $("#project-button-textarea-for-testing").val( code ).trigger("set-live-editor");
    });
};
```

and

```
casper.thenClick( "#project-bar-yes-no-modal.in button.modal-no", function() { 
    casper.setLiveEditorCode( "ellipse(100, 100, 100, 101);\n\n" );
    this.wait(200);
} );
```

"1" is displays in the output, "2" is not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the code inside evaluate is executed by browser, and `utils` object is not defined in js environment of browser...

```
casper.setLiveEditorCode = function( code ) {
    utils.dump("1");//here is casperjs js environment, and utils is imported by casperjs bootstrap.js
    casper.evaluate(function(){
        utils.dump("2"); //here browser js environment, and utils is not defined in that scope...
    });
};
```

Read the [official docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) about `evaluate` for further information.

Comment: That is right. Still it doesn't seem to execute the $("#project-button-textarea-for-testing").val ... line.

Comment: @Michael Could you please post your whole script out? I can't say anything without that...

Comment: Here you find the full test code: https://c2064.org/uit.js . You can start it with "casperjs test uit.js" Version 1 works, Version 2, which is currently commented out, doesn't.